# Unbound DAC Processing Screen

Tags: acumatica

I am having trouble getting the individual select check to work on my processing screen.  The DAC is unbound composed of data from several tables. Process All works correctly, but I cannot check individual rows.  I get an error stating "Error: The argument is out of range. Parameter name: table.

[image]

Process All results:
[image]

I have tried a variety of combinations of attributes and have had no luck.  My code is below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.SM;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes;
using LingoInterface;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace EDIASNs
{
    public class EDInventoryProcess : PXGraph<EDInventoryProcess>
    {
        public PXCancel<EDInventoryFilter> Cancel;
        public PXFilter<EDInventoryFilter> Filter;

        [PXFilterable]

        public PXFilteredProcessingOrderBy<EDInventory, EDInventoryFilter,
            OrderBy<Asc<EDInventory.partnerID, Asc<EDInventory.inventoryCD>>>> EDItem;

        protected virtual IEnumerable eDItem()
        {
            int ii = 0;
            foreach (var row in EDItem.Cache.Cached)
            {
                ii++;
                yield return row;
            }
            Int32 rowCntr = 0;
            if (ii == 0)
            {
                var cmd = new PXSelectJoin<InventoryItem,
                    InnerJoin<INItemXRef, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INItemXRef.inventoryID>>,
                    InnerJoin<EDPartnerInfo, On<INItemXRef.bAccountID, Equal<EDPartnerInfo.customerID>>>>,
                    Where<INItemXRef.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.cPN>,
                        And<InventoryItem.itemStatus, Equal<InventoryItemStatus.active>>>>(this);

                if (this.Filter.Current.TradingPartner != null)
                {
                    cmd.WhereAnd<Where<EDPartnerInfo.partnerID, Equal<Current<EDInventoryFilter.tradingPartner>>>>();
                }

                cmd.View.Clear();
                var ret = cmd.Select();
                if (ret != null)
                {
                    EDInventoryFilter filt = (EDInventoryFilter)Filter.Cache.Current;
                    EDInventory edInv = new EDInventory();
                    foreach (PXResult<InventoryItem, INItemXRef, EDPartnerInfo> record in ret)
                    {
                        edInv = new EDInventory();
                        InventoryItem item = (InventoryItem)record;
                        INItemXRef xref = (INItemXRef)record;
                        EDPartnerInfo partner = (EDPartnerInfo)record;

                        edInv.InvID = Guid.NewGuid();
                        rowCntr++;
                        edInv.IntID = rowCntr;
                        edInv.PartnerID = partner.PartnerID;
                        edInv.InventoryID = item.InventoryID;
                        edInv.InventoryCD = item.InventoryCD;
                        edInv.ItemDescr = item.Descr;
                        edInv.ItemStatus = item.ItemStatus;
                        edInv.BaseUnit = item.BaseUnit;
                        edInv.SalesUnit = item.SalesUnit;
                        edInv.PurchaseUnit = item.PurchaseUnit;
                        edInv.BasePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(item.BasePrice);
                        edInv.BaseWeight = item.BaseWeight;
                        edInv.BaseVolume = item.BaseVolume;
                        edInv.BaseItemWeight = item.BaseItemWeight;
                        edInv.BaseItemVolume = item.BaseItemVolume;
                        edInv.WeightUOM = item.WeightUOM;
                        edInv.VolumeUOM = item.VolumeUOM;
                        //edInv.NoteID = item.NoteID;
                        edInv.PartnerCustomerID = partner.CustomerID;
                        edInv.CustomerItem = xref.AlternateID;
                        edInv.CustomerItemDescr = xref.Descr;

                        var cmdAttrib = new PXSelect<CSAnswers,
                            Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>>>(this);
                        cmdAttrib.View.Clear();
                        var retAttrib = cmdAttrib.Select(item.NoteID);
                        if (retAttrib != null)
                        {
                            foreach (PXResult<CSAnswers> recAttrib in retAttrib)
                            {
                                CSAnswers ans = (CSAnswers)recAttrib;
                                switch (ans.AttributeID)
                                {
                                    case "CASEQTY":
                                        edInv.CaseQty = Convert.ToInt32(ans.Value);
                                        break;
                                    case "CASEL":
                                        edInv.CaseL = Convert.ToDecimal(ans.Value);
                                        break;
                                    case "CASEW":
                                        edInv.CaseW = Convert.ToDecimal(ans.Value);
                                        break;
                                    case "CASEH":
                                        edInv.CaseH = Convert.ToDecimal(ans.Value);
                                        break;
                                    case "UPC":
                                        edInv.UPC = ans.Value;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        var cmdPrice = new PXSelect<ARSalesPrice,
                            Where<ARSalesPrice.priceType, Equal<PriceTypes.customer>,
                                And<ARSalesPrice.customerID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPrice.customerID>>,
                                And<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID>>,
                                And<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate, GreaterEqual<Required<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate>>>>>>>(this);
                        cmdPrice.View.Clear();
                        var retPrice = cmdPrice.Select(partner.CustomerID, item.InventoryID, this.Accessinfo.BusinessDate);
                        if (retPrice != null)
                        {
                            foreach (PXResult<ARSalesPrice> recPrice in retPrice)
                            {
                                ARSalesPrice price = (ARSalesPrice)recPrice;
                                edInv.CustomerPrice = price.SalesPrice;
                            }
                        }

                        int intOnHand = 0;
                        int intCommitted = 0;
                        int intOnOrder = 0;

                        var cmdStock = new PXSelectJoin<INSiteStatus,
                            InnerJoin<INSite, On<INSiteStatus.siteID, Equal<INSite.siteID>>>,
                            Where<INSite.active, Equal<True>,
                            And<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>>>>>(this);
                        cmdStock.View.Clear();
                        var retStock = cmdStock.Select(item.InventoryID);
                        if (retStock != null)
                        {
                            foreach (PXResult<INSiteStatus> recStock in retStock)
                            {
                                INSiteStatus stock = (INSiteStatus)recStock;
                                intOnHand += Convert.ToInt32(stock.QtyOnHand);
                                intCommitted += Convert.ToInt32(stock.QtySOShipped + stock.QtySOShipping);
                                intOnOrder += Convert.ToInt32(stock.QtyPOPrepared + stock.QtyPOReceipts);
                            }
                            edInv.OnHand = intOnHand;
                            edInv.Committed = intCommitted;
                            edInv.OnOrder = intOnOrder;
                        }

                        edInv = EDItem.Insert(edInv);
                        EDItem.Cache.SetStatus(edInv, PXEntryStatus.Held);
                        yield return edInv;
                    }
                }
                EDItem.Cache.IsDirty = false;
            }
        }

        public void EDInventoryFilter_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            EDInventoryFilter filterOld = (EDInventoryFilter)e.OldRow;
            EDInventoryFilter filterNew = (EDInventoryFilter)e.Row;
            if (filterOld.Action == filterNew.Action)       //Don't clear cache if only action changes
                EDItem.Cache.Clear();
        }

        public void EDInventoryFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get list of partners to set filter
            List<string> strPartnerList = new List<string>();
            strPartnerList.Clear();
            var filter = (EDInventoryFilter)e.Row;
            foreach (EDPartnerInfo partner in PXSelect<EDPartnerInfo>.Select(this))
            {
                strPartnerList.Add(partner.PartnerID);
            }
            if (strPartnerList.Count > 0)
                PXStringListAttribute.SetList<EDInventoryFilter.tradingPartner>
                    (sender, filter, strPartnerList.ToArray(), strPartnerList.ToArray());
            else
            {
                throw new PXException("No active partners found");
            }

            EDItem.SetProcessDelegate
            (
                delegate (List<EDInventory> list)
                {
                    var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDInventoryProcess>();
                    graph.InventorySync(filter, list);
                }
            );

            //Action must be selected for Process buttons to be available
            if (filter.Action == null || filter.Action == "")
            {
                EDItem.SetProcessVisible(false);
                EDItem.SetProcessAllVisible(false);
            }
        }

        public void EDInventory_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = (EDInventory)e.Row;
        }

        public void InventorySync(EDInventoryFilter filter, List<EDInventory> list)
        {
            //Create Lingo API object and login
            bool ediDemo = false;
            bool bolAtLeastOneError = false;

            Int32 cntr = 0;
            EDCompanyData edCompanyData = new EDCompanyData();
            foreach (EDCompanyData data in PXSelect<EDCompanyData,
                Where<EDCompanyData.active, Equal<Required<EDCompanyData.active>>>>.Select(this, true))
            {
                cntr++;
                if (data.Service == "DEMO")
                    ediDemo = true;
                edCompanyData = data;
            }
            if (cntr == 0)
                throw new PXException("No active Service Data entries!");
            if (cntr > 1)
                throw new PXException("More than one active Service Data entry!");
            var lingo = new LingoApi();
            //Set url for service
            lingo.Url = edCompanyData.Url;
            if (!ediDemo)
            {
                if (!lingo.Login(edCompanyData.EDIAccount, edCompanyData.EDILoginName, edCompanyData.EDIPassword, edCompanyData.EDIApiKey))
                    throw new PXException("Login to EDI system failed.");
            }

            //Initialize variables
            EdiItem updateItem = new EdiItem();
            bool bolNewItem = false;
            Regex rxNonDigits = new Regex(@"[^\d]+");

            foreach (EDInventory acItem in list)
            {
                //Check for existing item in EDI
                if (lingo.Login() || ediDemo)                                          //Refresh the login session
                {
                    if (!ediDemo)
                    {
                        LingoRetItem itemRet = lingo.RetrieveItem(acItem.PartnerID, acItem.InventoryCD);
                        if (itemRet && itemRet.Count != 0)        //Found Item
                        {
                            if (itemRet.Count > 1)
                            {
                                PXProcessing<EDInventory>.SetError(list.IndexOf(acItem), String.Format("More than 1 occurrence found: {0}", itemRet.Message));
                                bolAtLeastOneError = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                updateItem = itemRet.DataItem;      //Load existing item data and set flag
                                bolNewItem = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            updateItem = new EdiItem();         //Clear item object for new item and set flag
                            bolNewItem = true;
                        }
                    }
                    updateItem.account = edCompanyData.EDIAccount;
                    updateItem.partner = acItem.PartnerID;
                    if (bolNewItem)
                        updateItem.createDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    updateItem.upcCode = rxNonDigits.Replace(acItem.UPC, "");       //Remove non-numeric characters
                    updateItem.upcCodeType = "UPC";
                    updateItem.vendorItem = acItem.InventoryCD;
                    updateItem.vendorItemType = "VNDR";
                    updateItem.customerItem = acItem.CustomerItem;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acItem.CustomerItemDescr))
                        updateItem.itemDesc = acItem.ItemDescr;
                    else
                        updateItem.itemDesc = acItem.CustomerItemDescr;
                    if (acItem.BaseItemWeight > 0)
                        updateItem.itemWeight = acItem.BaseItemWeight.ToString();
                    else
                        updateItem.itemWeight = acItem.BaseWeight.ToString();
                    //Inventory Information
                    updateItem.qtyOnHand = acItem.OnHand.ToString();
                    updateItem.qtyCommitted = acItem.Committed.ToString();
                    updateItem.qtyOnOrder = acItem.OnOrder.ToString();
                    //Item Pricing Information
                    if (acItem.CustomerPrice > 0)
                        updateItem.unitPrice = acItem.CustomerPrice.ToString();
                    else
                        updateItem.unitPrice = acItem.BasePrice.ToString();
                    updateItem.priceBasis = acItem.SalesUnit;
                    //Item Packing and Carton Information
                    updateItem.unitMeasure = acItem.BaseUnit;
                    updateItem.packSize = acItem.CaseQty.ToString();
                    updateItem.cartonLength = acItem.CaseL.ToString();
                    updateItem.cartonWidth = acItem.CaseW.ToString();
                    updateItem.cartonHeight = acItem.CaseH.ToString();

                    LingoRet itemMaintResult = new LingoRet();
                    if (!ediDemo)
                        itemMaintResult = lingo.MaintainItem(updateItem, bolNewItem);
                    else
                    {
                        itemMaintResult.Code = "OK";
                        itemMaintResult.Message = "Success";
                    }
                    //Check result 
                    if (itemMaintResult.Code == "OK" || ediDemo)
                    {
                        PXProcessing<EDInventory>.SetInfo(list.IndexOf(acItem), 
                            String.Format(" Item {0} EDI: {1}", bolNewItem ? "added to" : "updated in",itemMaintResult.Message));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PXProcessing<EDInventory>.SetError(list.IndexOf(acItem), String.Format(" Item maintenance failed: {0}", itemMaintResult.Message));
                        bolAtLeastOneError = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    PXProcessing<EDInventory>.SetError(list.IndexOf(acItem), String.Format(" Lingo login failed: {0}", lingo.ResMessage));
                    bolAtLeastOneError = true;
                }
            }
            if (bolAtLeastOneError)
                throw new PXException("At least one item had exceptions");
        }

        [Serializable]
        public partial class EDInventoryFilter : IBqlTable
        {
            #region TradingPartner
            public abstract class tradingPartner : PX.Data.IBqlField
            {
            }
            protected string _TradingPartner;
            [PXString(15)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Trading Partner")]
            [PXStringList(new string[] { }, new string[] { })]
            public virtual String TradingPartner { get; set; }
            #endregion 

            #region Action
            public abstract class action : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected string _Action;
            [PXDefault("P")]
            [PXString(15)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Action")]
            [PXStringList(new string[] { "P" }, new string[] { "Push to EDI" })]
            public virtual String Action { get; set; }
            #endregion
        }

        [Serializable]
        public partial class EDInventory : IBqlTable
        {
            #region Selected
            public abstract class selected : IBqlField { }
            protected bool? _Selected = false;
            [PXBool]
            [PXDefault(false)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
            public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region InvID
            public abstract class invID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected Guid? _InvID;
            [PXGuid]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ID")]
            public virtual Guid? InvID { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region intID
            public abstract class intID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected int? _IntID;
            [PXInt(IsKey = true)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "intID")]
            public virtual int? IntID { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region PartnerID
            public abstract class partnerID : IBqlField { }
            [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true)]
            [PXDefault("")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Partner")]
            public virtual string PartnerID { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region InventoryID
            public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected Int32? _InventoryID;
            [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Visible = false)]
            public virtual Int32? InventoryID { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region InventoryCD
            public abstract class inventoryCD : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _InventoryCD;
            [PXDefault()]
            [InventoryRaw(IsKey = true, DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
            public virtual String InventoryCD { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region ItemDescr
            public abstract class itemDescr : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _ItemDescr;
            [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item Description")]
            public virtual String ItemDescr { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region ItemStatus
            public abstract class itemStatus : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _ItemStatus;
            [PXDBString(2, IsFixed = true)]
            [PXDefault("AC")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item Status", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
            public virtual String ItemStatus { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region BaseUnit
            public abstract class baseUnit : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _BaseUnit;
            [PXDBString]
            [PXDefault("")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Base Unit", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
            public virtual String BaseUnit { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region SalesUnit
            public abstract class salesUnit : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _SalesUnit;
            [PXDBString(6)]
            [PXDefault("")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sales Unit", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
            public virtual String SalesUnit { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region PurchaseUnit
            public abstract class purchaseUnit : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _PurchaseUnit;
            [PXDBString(6)]
            [PXDefault("")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Purchase Unit", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
            public virtual String PurchaseUnit { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region BasePrice
            public abstract class basePrice : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected Decimal? _BasePrice;
            [PXPriceCost()]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default Price", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
            public virtual Decimal? BasePrice { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region BaseWeight
            public abstract class baseWeight : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected Decimal? _BaseWeight;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Base Weight")]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            public virtual Decimal? BaseWeight { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region BaseVolume
            public abstract class baseVolume : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected Decimal? _BaseVolume;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Base Volume")]
            public virtual Decimal? BaseVolume { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region BaseItemWeight
            public abstract class baseItemWeight : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected Decimal? _BaseItemWeight;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Weight")]
            public virtual Decimal? BaseItemWeight { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region BaseItemVolume
            public abstract class baseItemVolume : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected Decimal? _BaseItemVolume;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Volume")]
            public virtual Decimal? BaseItemVolume { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region WeightUOM
            public abstract class weightUOM : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _WeightUOM;
            [PXDBString(6)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Weight UOM")]
            [PXDefault("")]
            public virtual String WeightUOM { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region VolumeUOM
            public abstract class volumeUOM : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected String _VolumeUOM;
            [PXDBString(6)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Volume UOM")]
            [PXDefault("")]
            public virtual String VolumeUOM { get; set; }
            #endregion
            /*
            #region NoteID
            public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            [PXGuid(IsKey = true)]
            [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            [PXNote]
            public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
            #endregion
            */
            #region PartnerCustomerID
            public abstract class partnerCustomerID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            [PXDBInt]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer")]
            [Customer(DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName))]
            public virtual Int32? PartnerCustomerID { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region CustomerItem
            public abstract class customerItem : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected string _CustomerItem;
            [PXDBString(50)]
            [PXDefault("")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer Item")]
            public virtual String CustomerItem { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region CustomerItemDescr
            public abstract class customerItemDescr : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            [PXDBString(60, IsUnicode = true)]
            [PXDefault("")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer Item Description")]
            public virtual String CustomerItemDescr { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region CaseQty
            public abstract class caseQty : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected int? _CaseQty;
            [PXDBInt]
            [PXDefault(0)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Case Qty")]
            public virtual Int32? CaseQty { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region CaseL
            public abstract class caseL : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected decimal? _CaseL;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Case Length")]
            public virtual Decimal? CaseL { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region CaseW
            public abstract class caseW : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected decimal? _CaseW;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Case Width")]
            public virtual Decimal? CaseW { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region CaseH
            public abstract class caseH : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected decimal? _CaseH;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Case Height")]
            public virtual Decimal? CaseH { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region CaseL
            public abstract class customerPrice : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected int? _CustomerPrice;
            [PXDBDecimal(6)]
            [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer Price")]
            public virtual Decimal? CustomerPrice { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region UPC
            public abstract class uPC : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected string _UPC;
            [PXDBString(20)]
            [PXDefault("")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "UPC Code")]
            public virtual String UPC { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region OnHand
            public abstract class onHand : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected int? _OnHand;
            [PXDBInt]
            [PXDefault(0)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "On Hand")]
            public virtual Int32? OnHand { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region Committed
            public abstract class committed : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected int? _Committed;
            [PXDBInt]
            [PXDefault(0)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Committed")]
            public virtual Int32? Committed { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region OnOrder
            public abstract class onOrder : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
            protected int? _OnOrder;
            [PXDBInt]
            [PXDefault(0)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "On Order")]
            public virtual Int32? OnOrder { get; set; }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have both DB Filed attributes and Non DB Field attributes. Besides, You even have a combination of Non DB and DB key fields in one DAC. It is not recommended.
So, first of all, make sure you have all key fields marked with either DB field or Non DB field attributes, but not a mixture of both.

Second, you can put [PXVirtualDAC] attribute to your EDItem view. It will prevent it from trying to go to a database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Dmitry.  I had originally had all non DB field attributes.  When that did not work, I tried various combinations over many tries which is how I ended up with a mixture.  The mystery of it is that I have this setup in 2 other pages that work perfectly.  Hopefully the PXVirtualDAC attribute will help.

Comment: I just got a chance to get back to this one.  The PXVirtualDAC attribute did the trick for allowing individual selection, but the crazy thing is that any non key (those without IsKey=true) columns revert to their defaults when selected so I end up with all nulls or 0 in the data.  I changed them all to non DB attributes.  Should I use DB attributes to hold the values?  Any other ideas?

Comment: Changing everything to DB types did nothing.  Adding IsKey to all the fields kept the values for processing.  I am sure this is not the correct solution, but for now it is working.